# Flutter everything going to the default route

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I was looking to extract the url parameters from within onGenerateRoute, and this doesnt seem to work, its not even going to the url

```
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/forgot-password':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return FutureBuilder(
                  future: test(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (
                      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                    ) {
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      return const Blank();
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            );
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {

            print(settings);

            return FutureBuilder(
              future: test(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (
                snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                ) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  return const LoginPage();
                }
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
```

When visiting /forgot-password?token=123, its printing

RouteSettings("/", null) with the login page and not the blank page